# Create This Sequence Using Only One Variable

Tags: c, sequence

How do you make a code in C that will output this sequence?

```
10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5
```

...easy!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int f = 10, s = 1;
while (s <= 5)
    printf("%d %d ",f--,s++);
getch();
}
```

There are many ways to do it, but as you might have noticed, it uses two variables.

So how do you re-create this using only ONE variable?

Comment: why would you want to do that? this seems rather be suited for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: codegolf.stackexchange.com , why?

Comment: Every other term is 11 - previous term.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a code golf style challenge rather than a practical problem.

Comment: `int a; printf ("10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5\n");`

Comment: Actually, if you wish to reduce the amount of variables for the sake of speed and readablity, the question makes perfect sense. I posted an example which improves both.

Comment: @n.m. LOL, that's funny! you won't need a variable that way! xDD
but seriously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code using a single var:

```
int main()
{
    int s = 1;
    while (s <= 5)
    {
        printf("%d %d ", (11-s), s);
        s++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Wow! Thanks.

Comment: @AX3M Close the question as answered.

Comment: It is better to avoid magic numbers... 11, 5... where did they come from?

Comment: @LPs btw, why did you just change it from "12" to "11" ? "12" worked fine.

Comment: @AX3M If you try to compile your code with `-Wall` option and the `s++` inside the `printf` you will warned about: _warning: operation on ‘s’ may be undefined_

Comment: @LPs ah, thanks for that. I am using Dev-C++ 5.11, btw.

Comment: @AX3M The Dev-C++ IDE is no longer maintained. I would recommend that you upgrade to something more modern. If you like Dev-C++, then CodeBlocks is a great IDE, which also uses the GCC compiler just like Dev-C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const int MAX = 10;

  for(int i=0; i<MAX/2; i++)
  {
    printf("%d, %d, ", MAX-i, i+1);
  }
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the solution OP was looking for.

Comment: @Fanax Why not? It uses 1 variable, it is readable and it will optimize much better than the original. Is there a reason why you would want to make my code less readable or slower?

Comment: No, I see your point. The question is not clearly formulated but I understood it as a question for an alternative algorithm. Your code is of course improving OP's code.